# Commenting moves point unexpectedly

Tags: org-mode, comment

The usual behavior of `comment-line` is to move point to the next line.
When commenting code within an Org source block, however, the point will jump to some previous line.

For example, say that point is at `|`:

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun hello ()
    "Say hi."
    (interactive)|
    (message "Hello, world!"))
#+end_src
```

When `comment-line` is called, the current line is commented, but point also moves to the indent of the previous line:

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun hello ()
    |"Say hi."
    ;; (interactive)
    (message "Hello, world!"))
#+end_src
```

Ideally, I would like point to not move at all (relative to the adjacent characters prior to (un)commenting) but would at least like `comment-line` to behave in a source block like it does outside of one.

I've tried a variety of [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688748/emacs-comment-uncomment-current-line) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041904/eclipse-like-line-commenting-in-emacs/20064658#20064658).  They all move point similarly.  It looks like `comment-or-uncomment-region` is the typical entry point.  This function leads down quite a labyrinth.  AFAIK, it ultimately hinges on the `comment-region-function` which is `comment-region-default-1` by default.  Stepping through, it's not clear to me which part moves point to a previous line.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce this. Maybe report it to the ML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue has been noticed and addressed by the `org-comment-dwim-2` function within the `comment-dwim-2` package.

```lisp
(defun org-comment-dwim-2 (&optional arg)
  "Call `comment-dwim-2' inside source blocks. Else, fallback to `org-toggle-comment'."
  (interactive "*P")
  (if (org-in-src-block-p t)
      (org-babel-do-in-edit-buffer (call-interactively 'comment-dwim-2))
    (call-interactively 'org-toggle-comment)))
```

What it does is open the source block in an editing buffer (like with `C-c '`), does the comment stuff, and then backs out.  It also will call `org-toggle-comment` when not in a source block. For me, that changes the section header to a comment.

To have the `org-comment-dwim-2` fall back to `comment-dwim-2` instead, you can do something like:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") (lambda () 
                             (interactive) 
                              (if (org-in-src-block-p t)
                                (call-interactively 'org-comment-dwim-2)
                               (call-interactively 'comment-dwim-2))))
```

This will call `org-comment-dwim-2` in org source blocks and call `comment-dwim-2` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that I see is even worse when doing `C-x C-;` in an org emacs-lisp source block:

After `comment-line` adds the ";;" characters at line start, the cursor jumps to the line after the `defun` declaration, which could be several lines above.  Note that this does not happen when doing the same thing when editing elisp code in an emacs-lisp buffer.

The only work-around that I've come up with is: `C-a` `C-@` `C-e` `C-f` `M-;`

Alternatively, create a macro and bind a key to it:

```
(fset 'comment-line-goto-next
   (kmacro-lambda-form [?\C-a ?\C-@ ?\C-e ?\C-f ?\M-\;] 0 "%d"))
```

Hope this helps.